# Tailwind background images bouncing around on mobile

Tags: css, tailwind-css, nuxtjs3

I've encountered an annoying problem with Tailwind CSS on Nuxt3. Whenever I'm on mobile, the browser's nav menu causes the bg image to jump around, i.e: when the bottom navbar comes up for my mobile browser it causes the bg image to jump up (and jump down when it retracts).

Is there any way to tell mobile browsers I want the bg image to stay put?

The layout template:

```
<template>
<div class="w-full min-h-screen
            bg-offblack
            text-milk">
  <div class="min-h-screen
              overflow-y-auto overflow-hidden
              grid grid-rows-1 grid-cols-1
              justify-items-center
              bg-fixed bg-right-bottom bg-no-repeat bg-[url('~/assets/images/ui/decker_mobile.png')]
              md:grid-cols-2
              lg:bg-[url('~/assets/images/ui/decker_desktop.png')]">
    <slot />
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Do you have something visual or a repro? https://play.tailwindcss.com/

Comment: I will try to recreate it in the sandbox tonight.

Comment: This should work I'll test it on my phone https://play.tailwindcss.com/1FxdasvJEv

Comment: Oh you're facing this issue I guess: https://www.bram.us/2021/07/08/the-large-small-and-dynamic-viewports/ By "navbar" you mean the menu of your browser, the UI part of the app itself not the website.

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: I recommend that you try either the ugly fix, or use the brand new viewport units so.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like tailwind doesn't support the new viewport units. I tried throwing the ugly fix into my tailwind.css in assets but it didn't appear to take effect. Is there an example of a Nuxt3 app with the fix implemented? I see some suggestions to use PostCSS but IIRC it wasn't compatible last I checked.

Comment: If it's not in Tailwind, it's not a big deal. Drop a line of vanilla CSS, won't break your website nor impact the performance.